# Unable to Install Swirl in "R"

Tags: r, swirl

Please help me in installing and loading the `swirl` package in R.

When I type:

```
install.packages("swirl")
```

I get:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Abdullah/Documents/R/win-library/3.3' (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/swirl_2.4.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 212366 bytes (207 KB)
downloaded 207 KB

package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Abdullah\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpeOgzVN\downloaded_packages
```

The package shows as being installed:

```
packageVersion("swirl")
```

> [1] ‘2.4.2’

But when I go to load it:

```
library(swirl)
```

I receive an error:

> Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
>     there is no package called ‘R6’
>   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Comment: Does [that](https://github.com/swirldev/swirl/issues/83) help?

Answer (score 0):

The error "There is no package called 'R6'" tells you that you need that package installed as well. Running `install.packages("R6");library(R6)` should take care of that.

The swirl package load the testthat package, which loads the R6 package. Since you don't have R6 installed, you can't load testthat, and you can't load swirl.